# Why it cant read my index?

Tags: php, session, indexing

```
  <?php 

        if($_SESSION['username'] == NULL)
        {
            print "Нямаш права да си тука";

        }
        else
        {
        if(isset($_POST['add']))


    {
        $time = time();
        $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
        $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);
        $q = "INSERT INTO posts(title,content,author,added) VALUES('$title','$content','Papazov','$time')";
        mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
        ?>
```

Why it says

**Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\MatchZone2\Addpost.php on line 17**

for the index in the session in the begging ?

Comment: Have you tried to google such a error message? **EVERY** single newbie asks about it, you're not unique

Comment: Note #1: make sure to correctly "start" the session each PHP load - otherwise the data truly will end up missing.

Comment: Note #2: the SQL snippet is fundamentally flawed. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION['username'] is undefined, so it's giving you undefined.

This would be correct:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

}
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry for editing your post with my answer ;) disregard please

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read an index that doesn't exist in the `$_SESSION` array. Add `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))`

Your code would then become:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])
{
    // I can't read the following, but I assume it should be displayed if the username is missing.
    print "Нямаш права да си тука";

}
else
{

}
```

For more on [isset](https://www.php.net/isset)